# How to get arp table information of other local area networks, including MAC address?

Tags: networking, ip, mac-address, arp

How to get arp table information of other local area networks, including MAC address?
Have any tools or code? If there is a solution, it is also very good.

Comment: I assume you mean something a little more than `arp -a` on a *nix box. Is there a particular programming language you're interested in?

Comment: `arp -a` can only get the MAC address of the local LAN device, but I need the MAC address of the non-local LAN

Comment: There's no way to programmatically do what you're asking for. ARP requests don't leave the local subnet, and there's no native TCP/IP mechanism to ask a host on another network what their MAC address is because (among other things), you don't ever need it.